# how to fill in values in a vector?

Tags: r, vector

I have vectors in R containing a lot of 0's, and a few non-zero numbers.Each vector starts with a non-zero number.

For example <1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0>

I would like to set all of the zeros equal to the most recent non-zero number.

I.e. this vector would become <1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4>

I need to do this for a about 100 vectors containing around 6 million entries each. Currently I am using a for loop:

```
for(k in 1:length(vector){

  if(vector[k] == 0){

    vector[k] <- vector[k-1]
  }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the vector sequential other than the zeros? If so, I think you should be able to use `cummax`. ie: `vector <- cummax( vector )`

Comment: I'd think mostly the former, but really just boosting it as a good point. I didn't specifically up-vote, but I do think it's a great suggestion.

Comment: If you hover over the upvote arrow, it says "this comment adds something useful to the post".  I think that is exactly what it means. Maybe not a full answer, but adds something useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option, would be to replace those `0` with `NA`, then use `zoo::na.locf`:

```
x <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0)
x[x == 0] <- NA
zoo::na.locf(x)  ## you possibly need: `install.packages("zoo")`
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4
```

---

Thanks to Richard for showing me how to use `replace`,

```
zoo::na.locf(replace(x, x == 0, NA))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try  this:

```
k <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0)
k[which(k != 0)[cumsum(k != 0)]]
```

or another case that `cummax` would not be appropriate

```
k <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
k[which(k != 0)[cumsum(k != 0)]]
```

Logic:

- I am keeping "track" of the indices of the vector elements that are non zero `which(k != 0)`, lets denote this new vector as `x`, `x=c(1, 7, 13)`
- Next I am going to "sample" this new vector. How? From `k` I am creating a new vector that increments every time there is a non zero element `cumsum(k != 0)`, lets denote this new vector as `y` `y=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)`
- I am "sampling" from vector `x`: `x[y]` i.e. taking the first element of `x` 6 times, then the second element 6 times and the third element 3 times. Let denote this new vector as `z`, `z=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 13, 13, 13)`
- I am "sampling" from vector `k`, `k[z]`, i.e. i am taking the first element 6 times, then the 7th element 6 times then the 13th element 3 times.

Comment: This is really clever, but the functionality is a little opaque, at least to me (I had to pull it apart and actually run it a step at a time to figure it out). I think it would be great if you could add a brief explanation of what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Add to @李哲源's answer:

If it is required to replace the leading NAs with the nearest non-NA value, and to replace the other NAs with the last non-NA value, the codes can be:

```
x <- c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0)
zoo::na.locf(zoo::na.locf(replace(x, x == 0, NA),na.rm=FALSE),fromLast=TRUE)
# you possibly need: `install.packages("zoo")`
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4
```